# syntax error unexpected 'mysql_query' (t_string)

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for asking this question, but I really got stucked with the problem.
It seems to me that the code is correct with no syntax errors due to it was copypasted from web and checked in phpmyadmin.
But I still have this annoying problem. Give me advice please. Where I am wrong?

```
        //$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(name, telephone) VALUES('abc', '123')";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE name='abc' AND telephone='123'";
        $host = 'localhost';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        $db_name = 'db_name';

        mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password, $db_name )
        mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `;` here:

```
mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password, $db_name )
                                                      ^-- here
```

Comment: Yep! gracias! My eyes were too tired to take a look at a few lines below. Thank you again